# Analisi logica di frasi e apposizione parola termine

Tags: sentences, grammatical-analysis

Nella frase:

> È considerata una manifestazione patologica negli adulti

"negli adulti" è un complemento di luogo? perché risponde alla domanda 'dove?' è giusto?

> Con il termine hardware indichiamo...

"Con il termine" che complemento è? di unione?

> Lui si trova in una bella situazione.

"in una situazione" è un complemento di luogo?

Inoltre

> Il termine privatizzazione indica...

La parola "termine" è un'apposizione?

Comment: Per curiosità, nel tuo esempio “Con il termine hardware si intende...” qual è secondo te il soggetto (di cui ipotizzi che faccia parte “con il termine”)?

Comment: @DaG grazie mi ero confuso

Comment: @Edoardo de Cal: "apposizione" è una parola femminile; l'articolo indeterminativo, quindi, è un', con l'apostrofo. (Inoltre, non è un'apposizione, bensì il soggetto: in generale, se posso permettermi, questo tipo di analisi non ha una grande utilità…)

Comment: @Benedetta: " Il termine "privatizzazione" " sembra una costruzione simile a "il signor Paolo", però: "signore" specifica meglio la persona di nome Paolo, così come "termine" specifica meglio la parola "privatizzazione", o sbaglio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"negli adulti" è complemento di limitazione, esattamente come lo è "in matematica" in "Sei bravo in matematica?".

Per identificare questo o quel complemento, è utile sostituire nella frase alcune espressioni paradigmatiche.  Ad esempio "con il termine 'hardware' indichiamo " vuol dire "mediante il termine 'hardware' indichiamo", quindi si tratta di un complemento di mezzo. Non è di unione perché non risponde alla domanda "insieme a chi/cosa?".

"in una situazione" è complemento di stato in luogo figurato, sì.

Per l'ultimo dubbio, attendo pareri nei commenti.